# Compiling thesis returns non-specific "Unused Global Option(s)" Error

Tags: sharelatex, options

I'm compiling my thesis, and the same error is constantly returned:
[image]

It's frustrating as in all the other forum posts I have found, the error has referred to a specific thing (such as: `Unused global option(s) [english]`) so it is possible to find the section of code at fault. Since my error just states `main.tex` it is very difficult to find the issue.

EDIT: added MWE:

```
%------METADATA-------
\def\myauthor{Author} % Author
\def\mytitle{Title} % title

%% ----------------------------Setting up the Preamble---------------------------

\documentclass[12pt,oneside,onehalfspacing]{report}  %[font size, same margins 
on both sides, line spacing] - ***change to twoside if getting bound!!!***
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  %input coding method
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  %makes copy and pasteable
\usepackage{graphicx}   %allows input of images
\usepackage{float}   %positioning of figures
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }  %where the images are kept
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}  %stops titles using too much space

\pagenumbering{roman} %set front matter page numbering to roman

%%----------PAGE LAYOUT--------
\usepackage[a4paper,left=40mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} %adds page headers
\setlength{\headwidth}{150mm}

\fancyhead{}  %clears header format
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} %adds chapter title in left position
\fancyhead[R]{\myauthor}  %adds author in right position
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage}} %bold page number


\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} %alters head/foot ruler line width
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} % header height

\setlength{\parskip}{1em} %adds return between paragraphs

%%------Font-------
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the 
document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%---------------------------------

\title{
    {\mytitle}\\
    \vspace{15mm}
%   {\large UoD}
    \vspace{10mm}
{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{dundee_logo.png}}\\
\vspace{5mm}
}
\author{\myauthor}
\date{2017}

%------------------BIBTEX------------------------
\usepackage[style=nature,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{isbn}}    % clears isbn
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{url}}    % clears url
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{doi}}    % clears doi
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issn}}    % clears issn
\usepackage{hyperref} %treats in text references as hyperlinks

%% --------------------------------End of Preamble--------------------------------------
\begin{document}
Here is my document
\end{document}
```

Sorry for the terrible LaTex writing, this is my first attempt at using it!

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's a generic error and we can't answer with this much info. where is your thesis style file? You can remove all the content and leave the preamble with a simple dummy document that replicates the error so we can have a look.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a minimal example that replicates the behaviour on [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com):

```
\documentclass[notused]{article}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum.

\end{document}
```

In order to identify the "global option that wasn't used", you have to click on View Raw Logs:

[image]

Then you can scroll through the log (towards the bottom) and find the actual warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [notused].
```

This is probably a bug in the ShareLaTeX engine, or [could be submitted as a feature request](https://www.sharelatex.com/about). I think the interpretation of the `.log` by the ShareLaTeX engine assumes the `LaTeX Warning` will be available on the line that it's published in the `.log`. However, since the list of unused options is displayed in the subsequent line, it only reports `Unused global option(s)` as the warning. For example, consider the warnings and their display in the following example:

```
\documentclass[notused]{article}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum \ref{abc}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [notused].

...

LaTeX Warning: Reference `abc' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.

...

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Werner ! I had a look in the raw logs and it turns out the issue is with my `onehalfspacing` command in the `\documentclass` line - I'll post an MWE in an edit to my question.